# Extracting parts of an image based on a grid mask

Tags: c++11, image-processing, opengl-es, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have been checking some jigsaw puzzle games around and I have noticed some of them use a grid image to extract pieces from an image. The image that represent the grid of pieces to extract is an image with white lines (the contour of pieces) and all the rest is just transparent. I have been struggling looking for ways to use this image to extract the pieces for my own game but haven't figured out how to do it.

Could anyone give any tip about how to use this image to extract the pieces?

An example of the image can be seen here. Take into account I have painted the white lines with a blue color to make it visible here at stack overflow:

[image]

P.D. Thinking a bit more about it, the only solution I found but I think it is too slow though is use something like a flood fill algorithm to extract the pixels and build the image set using piece center as starting points. This method could be used for any set of pieces with a regular width/height.

Cheers.

Comment: I do not have a good idea about fast extraction of these segments but if I were creating such a puzzle game I would create an algorithm which would take the number of rows and columns to be applied to the image and created a grid. Then for each pair where two puzzles connect I would use random to generate how the peaces fit together and create a shape from it. From here on you may generate vertex and texture coordinates or a black and white image to mask the texture and keep with squares. In any case you now have a randomly generated puzzle that can be applied to any image...

Comment: Yep, this is the ussual way to create a jigsaw. But, I wanted to know how this guys could achieve it with the given requirements. Beside the flood fill algorithm I couldn't come across any other way to do it. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out ;).

Comment: Well there might be a way just following a line. If for instance a line was always a pixel length you will know you can start in any corner and just follow the path... It should be fairly quick since the image resolution does not need to be very large. But the algorithm itself would present as recursive which would then needed to be restructured to lose the recursion for larger grids.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this too but throw it to the thrash can becase I felt it was too dirty :). Perhaps I should be reviewing it again. Anyway the odd thing about hte previous posted image is that guides are not just 1 pixel and lines have some kind of antialias applied too. :O

Comment: Would be interested in the solution you find...

Comment: ok, will try to sketch it up in the next days.